# Set same picklist value

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity, picklist, update

We are planning to set a new picklist field with the same values as the recordtype field. In order to keep the old values we need to (temporary) update the values of the new filed with the actual values of the recordtype field for historic values, and then update the values of the recordtype field and keep the old values in the new picklist field. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like a task for the data loader?

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)

Seems to be the best way to replicate the values I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Dataloader or run a script to update the new Picklist Field with the RecordType.DeveloperName - you can use a Report or a simple SOQL query to pull the Data out to Excel sheet (this way you will have Backup too..) 
    then you have your RecordType old Values in Place
2. Now you can just update all records with the Master RecordType you want. 
    BTW this can be done in the same operation.

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)

Seems to be the best way to replicate the values I need